# Can't generate an OpenAPI

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have been working through the tutorial:  [Getting started with Endpoints Frameworks for Python](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#generating_the_openapi_document) same as this person [How do I fix OpenAPI document generation on Google Cloud Endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455146/how-do-i-fix-openapi-document-generation-on-google-cloud-endpoints)
and I'm having a similar problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 28, in <module>
    from endpoints._endpointscfg_impl import main
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .apiserving import *
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 71, in <module>
    from endpoints_management.control import client as control_client
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints_management/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import auth, config, control, gen
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints_management/auth/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import suppliers, tokens
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints_management/auth/suppliers.py", line 21, in <module>
    from jwkest import jwk
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/jwkest/jwk.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 78, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import OSRNG
ImportError: cannot import name OSRNG
```

when I run this line with my project-ID

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_openapi_spec main.EchoApi --hostname [YOUR_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com
```

any idea if this is a bug that can be fixed

Comment: What version of Python are you using? You should be using Python2.7 and install the packages using the `pip` command relative to Python2.7. (You can check by using the command `pip --version` and `python --version`, both should indicate Python2.7 as the interpreter)

Comment: I have no idea what was the problem, but reinstalling the OS solved it.